# How to use different nsfetchrequest for different sections in NSfetchedresultcontroller within a tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to populate a uitableview with two different set of fetchrequest.
I do have one nsfetchedresultcontroller and I want to create two nsfetchrequest: #1, #2.
Basically, all results from #1 will be in the first section and #2 will be in the second section.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're interested in using an alternative to `NSFetchedReseultsController`, I can help you solve this using [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) by subclassing `TLIndexPathController`. Take a look at some of the sample projects, particularly the Core Data one. I would not recommend if you're table view is going to have more than a few thousand items at a time.

Comment: Timothy, I checked TLIndexPathTools. There won't be 100+ items at a time, but each item is rather complex. I think tableview handles it better.

Comment: No problem. But TLIndexPathTools is a collection of components that simplify building table & collection views. It doesn't replace table views. One of the things it does is provide an alternative to `NSFetchedResultsController` with a number of improvements. It is easy to extend for solving problems like yours.